# ASP.NET MVC Add View Dialog missing options

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am following the NerdDinner tutorial

http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part4.htm

and have gotten to "Adding a View" (middle of the page). When i right-click the controller and select "Add view", i get a dialog that is mising the "View Content" and the "ContentPlaceHolder ID" options.

Does anyone know why i cant see these options?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using the released version of MVC.  The additions to the View dialog aren't available in at least some of the earlier versions.